# Do moving armies still receive reinforcements in Blight of the Immortals

Tags: blight-of-the-immortals

If I reinforce my army and then order it to move, will it still receive the reinforcements?

Also, is reinforcement size the same as the new army size?

Answer (score 1):

Just answered my own question.

Yes, they do receive the reinforcements even while moving.